# Storing only last value of a variable over a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

Let's say I have a list of objects, the goal is to write a recursive function that output a list of objects whose weights are below some threshold.

For example if `L= [A,B,C,D]`, and I have a function that computes the weights of the objects A, B and C, where respectively `W =[12,7,32,14]`. The output should be a list of tuple that is, if the threshold is 13, the output should be: `[(C,32),(D,14)]`.

I wrote the recursive function (based on binary search) that does that but I also want to include the weights in the output.

I can not include the whole code (because it's too long), but here's the main part of interest,

```
def recursive_find(self, L,n):
        k = L[0] 
        S = L[1] 
        current_weight
        if k == n 
            return [(S,current_weight)]
        extended_S = np.copy(S)
        extended_S[k] = 1
        next_L = [(k + 1, S), (k + 1, extended_S)]
        B = []
        for new_L in next_L:
            current_weight = self.sample_weight(new_L)
            if current_weight > self.tau ** 2 / 2:
                B += self.recursive_find(new_L)
        return B
```

If I run the code I get all `current_weight` zeroes, which makes sense because L call recursive function and new `current_weight` is initialized back to 0.

The question isn't specific to this problem, but in a general way when dealing with recursive functions in python. The problem is, in recursive functions, it is not possible to keep track of this additional variable: weight. Is there a possible way to solve that?

Comment: Please include the code of the function you write, with an example of the call to the function and the desired result for that call.

Comment: _but I also want to include the weights in the output_ So ... do that.  What, exactly, is stopping you?

Comment: I included a part of the code where the problem occurs, I hope it makes it clear.

Comment: You could change the recursive function so it takes `current_weight` as an argument, just like the other arguments.

Comment: I couldn't see variable "W" value. Are you taking "W" as argument? From my understanding "n" in threshold value.

Comment: @JohnGordonv, I can't upvote your comment I don't know why, but thanks it worked

Comment: @Venkat to compute the wieght I call another function in the class, and n is not the threshold its the dimension of the vector (the object of interest), tau**2\2 is the threshhold

Comment: I don't understand how the problem has to do with recursion or binary search. Won't `[x for x in zip(L, W) if x[1] > some_threshold]` do the job?